# Import Multiple Nested Tree XML using pd.read_xml as DF

Tags: python, pandas, xml, xml-parsing

I have been building a program to get some values needed in a large XML file.  I found the pandas.read_xml() function and am wondering if anyone has tried to complete something like following:

Instead of me creating a large looping function to get all the values I need (from different layers of the Tree) into a DF, is there a way I can loop through each Node and append to a single DF?

For example, Is there a way I can get everything single node into a DF by looping through?  I have nothing to join the DF's on after if I created them separately so I'm not sure how I can achieve this.

Something like

```
nodes = ['//node1','//node2','//node3','//node4']

for i in nodes:

   # Do something here to read the xml, store in a DF, the next iteration JOIN the new Nodes?
   pd.read_xml('xmltest.xml', xpath=i)
```

The end result would look like

```
node1Value | node2Value | node3Value | node4Value
-------------------------------------------------
 ID123     |    ID5     |   test1    |    value
 ID123     |    ID5     |   test1    |    value2
 ID123     |    ID5     |   test2    |    value
 ID123     |    ID5     |   test2    |    value2
 ID123     |    ID7     |   test1    |    value
 ID123     |    ID7     |   test1    |    value2
 ID123     |    ID7     |   test2    |    value
 ID123     |    ID7     |   test2    |    value2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the node names beforehand, you can hardcode them.

In that case you can use the `stylesheet` parameter of the `read_xml` function. But I do not know how to pass parameters to the stylesheet or how to merge dataframes.

So the following sample code does not use these things.
In all other cases, you can use this python code

```
dataFolder = './'
df_bulk = pd.read_xml(
    dataFolder+'input.xml', 
    stylesheet='transform.xslt',
    xpath='/Root/Item', 
    )
print(df_bulk.head(16))
```

where `transform.xslt` is the following XSLT stylesheet in the same directory:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>    
       
    <xsl:template match="/Root">
        <Root>
            <xsl:variable name="nodes"    select="*[starts-with(local-name(),'node')]" />
            <xsl:variable name="children" select="$nodes[1]/*" />
            <xsl:for-each select="$children">
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
                <Item>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
                        <xsl:element name="{concat(local-name(),'value')}"><xsl:value-of select="Value[$pos]" /></xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Item>                
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It preprocesses an `input.xml` file like the following

```
<Root>
    <node1>
        <Value>ID123</Value>
        <Value>ID123</Value>
        <Value>ID123</Value>
        <Value>ID123</Value>
        <Value>ID123</Value>
        <Value>ID123</Value>
        <Value>ID123</Value>
        <Value>ID123</Value>
    </node1>
    <node2>
        <Value>ID5</Value>
        <Value>ID5</Value>
        <Value>ID5</Value>
        <Value>ID5</Value>
        <Value>ID7</Value>
        <Value>ID7</Value>
        <Value>ID7</Value>
        <Value>ID7</Value>
    </node2>
    <node3>
        <Value>test1</Value>
        <Value>test1</Value>
        <Value>test2</Value>
        <Value>test2</Value>
        <Value>test1</Value>
        <Value>test1</Value>
        <Value>test2</Value>
        <Value>test2</Value>
    </node3>
    <node4>
        <Value>value</Value>
        <Value>value2</Value>
        <Value>value</Value>
        <Value>value2</Value>
        <Value>value</Value>
        <Value>value2</Value>
        <Value>value</Value>
        <Value>value2</Value>
    </node4>
</Root>
```

to an intermediate XML file like this:

```
 <Root>
    <Item>
        <node1value>ID123</node1value>
        <node2value>ID5</node2value>
        <node3value>test1</node3value>
        <node4value>value</node4value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <node1value>ID123</node1value>
        <node2value>ID5</node2value>
        <node3value>test1</node3value>
        <node4value>value2</node4value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <node1value>ID123</node1value>
        <node2value>ID5</node2value>
        <node3value>test2</node3value>
        <node4value>value</node4value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <node1value>ID123</node1value>
        <node2value>ID5</node2value>
        <node3value>test2</node3value>
        <node4value>value2</node4value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <node1value>ID123</node1value>
        <node2value>ID7</node2value>
        <node3value>test1</node3value>
        <node4value>value</node4value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <node1value>ID123</node1value>
        <node2value>ID7</node2value>
        <node3value>test1</node3value>
        <node4value>value2</node4value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <node1value>ID123</node1value>
        <node2value>ID7</node2value>
        <node3value>test2</node3value>
        <node4value>value</node4value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <node1value>ID123</node1value>
        <node2value>ID7</node2value>
        <node3value>test2</node3value>
        <node4value>value2</node4value>
    </Item>
</Root>
```

This intern file is transformed to a DataFrame by `read_xml` to

```
  node1value node2value node3value node4value
0      ID123        ID5      test1      value
1      ID123        ID5      test1     value2
2      ID123        ID5      test2      value
3      ID123        ID5      test2     value2
4      ID123        ID7      test1      value
5      ID123        ID7      test1     value2
6      ID123        ID7      test2      value
7      ID123        ID7      test2     value2
```

Comment: Thanks, I do know the nodes beforehand.  Do you know a great stylesheet/XSLT generator that I could use?

Comment: There _are no stylesheet generators_, because each stylesheet/requirement is different. If it was possible, this answer wouldn't exist. You have to customize the XSLT according to your personal needs. I gave you a verbose example. Learning basic XSLT is not easy, but "_we_" will probably assist you in that endeavor.

Comment: Thanks @zx485 !  I am new to parsing XML.  Sorry to offend, I do appreciate your comment and answer.  I think for my case, I may go with looping through as the XML is very dense and not an easy place to start with learning XSLT.  Maybe I will learn that on the side for the next time this comes around